# How can I convert a video to BPG format? BPG= Better portable graphics

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion

I am trying to embed video into my site. And since loading time is important, I want to implement it using BPG. 
The author of this post implemented it https://eek.ro/why-bpg-will-replace-gifs-and-not-only/

How can I do the same? I can find ways to convert jpeg to bpg, but when it comes to making a video in bpg format, I'm clueless.

Comment: Which BPG encoder are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like BPG is at quite an early stage of development.

To use it, you would need to install an encoder, to convert your video to the BPG format.  At the moment, all of these encoders are command-line only.  You can find links to the encoders [on the official site](http://bellard.org/bpg/).

Note that the format doesn't include audio currently, so it may only be useful in some circumstances.

You might be better using a more conventional video format (h264, mp4, webm), but concentrating on encoding it with the most appropriate bandwidth and quality settings for your needs.